# Why are func parameters immutable but constructor param can be mutable in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin, I just realised that function parameters are **immutable**:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/

> We removed support for mutable parameters, as in

```
fun foo(var x: Int) {
  x = 5
}
```

However for class constructors, it can be **mutable**:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

```
class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    var age: Int, // trailing comma
) { /*...*/ }
```

> Much like regular properties, properties declared in the primary constructor can be mutable (var) or read-only (val).

why? what's the use case of us having a mutable constructor parameters?

Comment: And I would also suggest reading that second link more carefully, about what the word `var` in a constructor parameter declaration actually means.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the questions with some snippets and mentions from the docs @Sweeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function parameter mutability is a frequent source of bugs in languages that allow it, so the Kotlin designers decided to disallow it.

In a primary constructor, the parameters that are preceded with `val` or `var` are not actually accessible because they are immediately converted into properties. You can have `init` blocks in your class, but they are working with the class properties, not the constructor's `val`/`var` parameters. Note, you can also define parameters in your constructor that are not properties, and these indeed are immutable in the `init` blocks.

When you define a `var` in a primary constructor, it is a class property.

Answer (score -1):

Function parameters are mutable. Here is the example,

```
data class Mutable(var mute:Int)

fun muteIt(mute: Mutable) {
    mute.mute = 20
}

fun main() {
    val testObj = Mutable(10)
    println(testObj)
    muteIt(testObj)
    println(testObj)
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/e3fZTV0sx?theme=darcula

True immutability in kotlin is achievable via `const val` and `val` only means read-only, not immutable precisely and you can only assign string literals and other primitive types to `const val`.